# Wordpress Anchor Child Page Titles (jQuery?)

Tags: jquery, wordpress

I'm designing a one page layout, so I made child pages display on their parent page using this code;

```
<?php
$mypages = get_pages( array( 'child_of' => $post->ID, 'sort_column' => 'post_date',     'sort_order' => 'desc' ) );

foreach( $mypages as $page ) {
    $content = $page->post_content;
    if ( ! $content ) // Check for empty page
        continue;

    $content = apply_filters( 'the_content', $content );
?>
    <h2><?php echo $page->post_title; ?></h2>
    <div class="entry"><?php echo $content; ?></div>
<?php
}
?>
```

And I'd like to add icons on the top that links to each child page. But I can't figure out how to anchor child page titles. I'd like to do this without a plugin if possible.

I'd really appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

to get the permalink SRC it's `$link = get_permalink($page->ID);`